# Update dynamoDB key that contains map

Tags: node.js, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using:

http://awspilot.github.io/dynamodb-oop/#query

(aws-sdk wrapper)

I have an object that is stored in DB.
I want to update a value that it's a map.

**This is my table:**

```
userId, myMap

123     {'abc': '123'}
```

**And this is the code:**

```
var tableName = 'myTable';
var userIdKey = 'userId';

function updateMyMap(userId, dic) {

    DynamoDB
    .table(tableName)
    .where(userIdKey).eq(userId)
    .return(DynamoDB.ALL_OLD)
    .insert_or_update({
        myMap: dic
    }, function( err, data ) {
        console.log( err, data )
    })
}
```

**First example:**

When I call `updateMyMap`:

```
updateMyMap('123', {'abc':'456', 'def':'555'});
```

I want the table to be:

```
userId, myMap

123     {'abc': '456', 'def':'555'}
```

**Second example:**

When I call `updateMyMap`:

```
updateMyMap('123', {'ghi':'222'});
```

I want the table to be:

```
userId, myMap

123     {'abc': '456', 'def':'555', 'ghi':'222'}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use an update expression in an UpdateItem call:

```
SET myMap.#key = :value
```

The other parameters would be:

```
ConditionExpression: attribute_exists(myMap)
ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#key": "ghi" }
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":value": 222 }
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks for sharing.